# All styles are looking for the site URL twice

Tags: migration, site-url

I am migrating a production server to a development server. I have archived the `public_html` folder and migrated the database and imported it to the new server without any problems.

When I load the dev site, I notice none of my styles load an in fact it's looking into the site URL twice.

e.g.,

> http://example.com/example.com/wp-content/...

I have checked the server subdomain settings and everything is pointing to the right folder.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the stylesheet href as relative path eg. `/example.com/wp-content/...` it will append it to the current location `http://example.com` in your browser, so for just a relative path use just `/wp-content/`.

But if you specify an absolute path eg. `http://example.com/wp-content/...` or even `//example.com/wp-content/` it will just look for that directly. Either way should hopefully bypass the problem you are having.